# How to deploy a new version of a smart contract to a testnet?

Tags: solidity, ether, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

So I have deployed a contract to the Rinkeby testnet but I have added some new features to it and I've tried deploying the contract again but it just says the following:

> √ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1.
>
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.
>
> Network up to date. Network up to date.

I am not sure what I need to do to get the new version up and running. I have used some of the following commands:

```
truffle migrate --reset
truffle migrate --network rinkeby
truffle compile
```

And they all print the same message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this command solved the problem apparently:

```
truffle migrate --reset --compile-all --network rinkeby
```

Comment: Something doesn't add up. `--reset` would only be needed if there is no difference between the latest bytecode and the bytecode already deployed. Or, if deploying multiple contracts and you want to start fresh. It doesn't seem to match up with "added new features" because that would result in different bytecode that the default command would deploy.

Comment: I have no idea why it didn't register changes on the contract but by using that command it deployed the new changed version.